# ANTLR doesn't match correct parser rule in some cases

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to identify figure namber in documents. Strings like "Figure 3. Caption" or "See in Figure 3". Some figure may contain subindex ('1A' or '1.1' or '3.A') and sometimes there is no space beetwen Caption and dot. I have the following ANTLR file with rules:

```
grammar Text;

text   : space? 
      ( 
       keywordFigure
      | label
      | space
      | dot
      | comma
      | word )*;


FIGURE : 'Figure';
keywordFigure : FIGURE;

LABEL_TOKEN : [0-9]+ [a-zA-Z]?
            | [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]+
            | [0-9]+ '.' [a-zA-Z];
label : LABEL_TOKEN;


/* Separators */

SPACE_TOKEN : [ \t\n\r]+;
space : SPACE_TOKEN;

DOT : '.';
dot : DOT;

COMMA : ',';
comma : COMMA;

fragment WORD_CHAR : ~[0-9 \t\n\r.,];
WORD_TOKEN : WORD_CHAR+;
word : WORD_TOKEN;
```

This grammar does not work correctly for some examples:

```
Figure 6.Regulation
```

*label* is "6.R" but not "6." because the ANTLR priority (select the lexer rule which matches the longest input).

```
See in Figure 2.1, 86Formula and other text
```

*labels* are "2.1" and "86F".

Is there a way how to identify a boundary for this rule?

Comment: Antlr Lexer rules are not parser-state dependent. Antlr lexer tokenizes the entire input first, then the parse starts.  The lexer matches the longest string regardless of rule order. If two lexer rules match the same string, the first rule listed is picked. So, `WORD_TOKEN` cannot match because `LABEL_TOKEN` occurs first. Also, always print out your tokens when debugging the grammar.

Comment: Since you’re (apparently ) just trying to find patterns in a document and not trying to identify the structure of the document, I’d really have to suggest that a Regex matcher is a much more appropriate tool than ANTLR for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Free text is more difficult to parse than programming languages. It's not the first time that I see answers discouraging to use ANTLR, like Mike's comment. Nevertheless I have tried to find a solution.

With your grammar, the lexer rule `LABEL_TOKEN` systematically consumes the first letter after a digit or digit dot, as can be seen when listing the tokens produced by the lexer :

```
% grun Text text -tokens input.txt 
[@0,0:5='Figure',<'Figure'>,1:0]
[@1,6:6=' ',<SPACE_TOKEN>,1:6]
[@2,7:9='6.R',<LABEL_TOKEN>,1:7]
[@3,10:18='egulation',<WORD_TOKEN>,1:10]
...
[@21,62:64='86F',<LABEL_TOKEN>,3:19]
[@22,65:70='ormula',<WORD_TOKEN>,3:22]
```

With this grammar in file `Question.g4` :

```
grammar Question;

text
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 2046");}
    :   line+ EOF ;

line
    :   ( figure
    |     ID
    |     NUMBER
    |     PUNCTUATION
    |     SPACE
        )+ NL?
    ;

figure
    :   'Figure' SPACE figure_number
    ;

figure_number
    :   NUMBER    
                           { System.out.println("NUMBER ID current tk txt=" + getCurrentToken().getText() + " line=" + getCurrentToken().getLine() + " pos=" + getCurrentToken().getCharPositionInLine()); }
        { getCurrentToken().getText().length() == 1 }? ID
                           { System.out.println("   >> C " + $start.getTokenIndex() + "-" + ($ID == null ? "?" : $ID.getTokenIndex()) + " text=" + ($ID == null ? $NUMBER.text : $NUMBER.text + $ID.text)); }
    |   NUMBER_DOT
                           { System.out.println("NUMBER_DOT ID current tk txt=" + getCurrentToken().getText() + " line=" + getCurrentToken().getLine() + " pos=" + getCurrentToken().getCharPositionInLine()); }
        { getCurrentToken().getText().length() == 1 }? ID
                           { System.out.println("   >> D " + $start.getTokenIndex() + "-" + ($ID == null ? "?" : $ID.getTokenIndex()) + " text=" + ($ID == null ? $NUMBER_DOT.text : $NUMBER_DOT.text + $ID.text)); }
    |   NUMBER_DOT NUMBER
                           { System.out.println("NUMBER_DOT NUMBER ID current tk txt=" + getCurrentToken().getText() + " line=" + getCurrentToken().getLine() + " pos=" + getCurrentToken().getCharPositionInLine()); }
        { getCurrentToken().getText().length() == 1 }? ID
                           { System.out.println("   >> E " + $start.getTokenIndex() + "-" + ($ID == null ? "?" : $ID.getTokenIndex()) + " text=" + ($ID == null ? $NUMBER_DOT.text : $NUMBER_DOT.text + $ID.text)); }
    |   NUMBER             { System.out.println("   >> A " + $start.getTokenIndex() + " text=" + $NUMBER.text); }
    |   NUMBER_DOT NUMBER? { System.out.println("   >> B " + $start.getTokenIndex() + " text=" + $NUMBER_DOT.text + $NUMBER.text); }
    ;

ID          : LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT )* ;
NUMBER      : DIGIT+ ;
NUMBER_DOT  : DIGIT+ '.' ;
PUNCTUATION : [.,;:!?\-()'"’] ;
NL          : [\r\n]+ ;
SPACE       : ' '+ ;
TAB         : [\t]+ -> skip ;

fragment DIGIT  : [0-9] ;
fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
```

and the following input in file `input.txt` :

```
Figure 6.Regulation
Figure 6 Regulation
Figure 6.1A Regulation
See in Figure 2.1, 86Formula and other text
See Figure 3A xyz.
See Figure 3.1A abc.

Since you’re (apparently ) just trying ... - to identify the structure -, I’d really suggest : a Regex matcher, see Figure 3A.
```

and given :

```
alias a4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar'
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar
```

Execution :

```
% a4 Question.g4                                              
% javac Q*.java 
% grun Question text -tokens -gui input.txt
[@0,0:5='Figure',<'Figure'>,1:0]
[@1,6:6=' ',<SPACE>,1:6]
[@2,7:8='6.',<NUMBER_DOT>,1:7]
[@3,9:18='Regulation',<ID>,1:9]
...
```

the grafic is quite nice and the output is :

```
Question last update 2046
NUMBER_DOT ID current tk txt=Regulation line=1 pos=9
line 1:9 rule figure_number failed predicate: { getCurrentToken().getText().length() == 1 }?
   >> A 7 text=6
NUMBER_DOT NUMBER ID current tk txt=A line=3 pos=10
   >> E 13-15 text=6.A
   >> B 25 text=2.1
NUMBER ID current tk txt=A line=5 pos=12
   >> C 42-43 text=3A
NUMBER_DOT NUMBER ID current tk txt=A line=6 pos=14
   >> E 52-54 text=3.A
NUMBER ID current tk txt=A line=8 pos=124
   >> C 112-113 text=3A
```

For the input `Figure 6.Regulation`, the semantic predicate

`{ getCurrentToken().getText().length() == 1 }?`

guards from using the first alternative, NUMBER ID, of rule figure_number.

To give a chance to alternatives C, D and E to be used, I had to move A and B at the end of rule figure_number. Explanation in section 15.7, [book](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference/) page 286, PDF page 288 :

> ANTLR’s general decision-making strategy is to find all viable
> alternatives and then ignore the alternatives guarded with predicates
> that currently evaluate to false. (A viable alternative is one that
> matches the current input.) If more than one viable alternative
> remains, the parser chooses the alternative specified first in the
> decision.

With

```
figure_number
    :   NUMBER             ...  >> A
    |   NUMBER_DOT NUMBER? ...  >> B
```

the parsing decisions give a completely different result :

```
Question last update 0853
   >> B 2 text=6.null
   >> A 7 text=6
   >> B 13 text=6.1
   >> B 25 text=2.1
   >> A 42 text=3
   >> B 52 text=3.1
   >> A 112 text=3
```

Just for completeness, it can be useful to have a listener, file `MyListener.java` :

```
public class MyListener extends QuestionBaseListener {
    QuestionParser parser;
    public MyListener(QuestionParser parser) { this.parser = parser; }

    public void exitLine(QuestionParser.LineContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(">>> in MyListener for line");
        System.out.println(parser.getTokenStream().getText(ctx));
    }
}
```

and an application, file `Job.java` :

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class Job {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("==========Java Job 4/1/2023 14:32");
        String input_file_name = "";

        if ( args.length < 1 )
            throw new Exception("Missing input file name on command line");

        input_file_name  = args[0];
        CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName(input_file_name);

        System.out.println("==========Java Job start parsing ==========");
        QuestionLexer     lexer    = new QuestionLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens   = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        QuestionParser    parser   = new QuestionParser(tokens);
        ParseTree         tree     = parser.text();
        System.out.println("==========Java Job parsing ended");
        ParseTreeWalker   walker   = new ParseTreeWalker();
        System.out.println("==========Java Job about to new MyListener");
        MyListener        listener = new MyListener(parser);
        System.out.println("==========Java Job about to walk");
        walker.walk(listener, tree);
        System.out.println("==========Java Job tree size=" + tree.getChildCount());
    }
}
```

which outputs the lines as seen by the parser :

```
% java Job input.txt
...
==========Java Job about to walk
>>> in MyListener for line
Figure 6.Regulation
...
>>> in MyListener for line
See in Figure 2.1, 86Formula and other text
```